# Update with Nested Select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got so far with this with some searching on this site, and experimenting, but I can't find the last step. 
I have a SQL table of track_id and track_data. I want the latter to be updated from text pulled in from other tables via various joins. I can so far get it to display the data for one track_id I have in the test table. But I want to UPDATE the track_data with what I can display for every track_id.

```
    track_id        track_data
    4560
    4561
```

My Select Query is

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT tdd.track_id, CONCAT(t.track_name, ' ',    t.track_description, ' ', t.keywords, ' ', tc.library_name, ' ', tc.label_name, ' ', tc.album_reference, ' ', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)) 
    FROM track_data AS tdd
    JOIN tracks t 
    ON tdd.track_id = t.track_id 
    JOIN tracks_cache tc 
    ON tc.track_id = t.track_id 
    JOIN categories_to_track ct 
    ON t.track_id = ct.track_id 
    JOIN categories c 
    ON c.category_id = ct.category_id
    ) AS trck
```

which outputs

```
    track_id        track_data
    4560            text text text from other tables categories etc
```

I want to UPDATE track_data with what I can view above, but also for every track_id in that table.

If I try adding SELECT trck.track_id at the start, it only shows me the one track id instead of all of them. 
And if I try wrapping it with

```
   UPDATE track_data SET track_data = (
   SELECT CONCAT(t.track_name, ' ', t.track_description, ' ', t.keywords, ' ', tc.library_name, ' ', tc.label_name, ' ', tc.album_reference, ' ', 
   GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)) 
   FROM testtrackdata AS tdd
   JOIN tracks t 
   ON tdd.track_id = t.track_id 
   JOIN tracks_cache tc 
   ON tc.track_id = t.track_id 
   JOIN categories_to_track ct 
   ON t.track_id = ct.track_id 
   JOIN categories c 
   ON c.category_id = ct.category_id
   ) AS trck
   WHERE track_data.track_id = trck.track_id
```

and other variations, I just get SQL Syntax errors that I can't work out. 
I'm sure I'm nearly there, but I need some helpful person from this neck of the woods to help me over the finish line.

Many thanks

Comment: Still struggling? Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT tdd.track_id, CONCAT(t.track_name, ' ',    t.track_description, ' ', t.keywords, ' ', tc.library_name, ' ', tc.label_name, ' ', tc.album_reference, ' ', 
GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)) 
FROM track_data AS tdd
JOIN tracks t 
ON tdd.track_id = t.track_id 
JOIN tracks_cache tc 
ON tc.track_id = t.track_id 
JOIN categories_to_track ct 
ON t.track_id = ct.track_id 
JOIN categories c 
ON c.category_id = ct.category_id
) AS trck
```

the outer query is not needed, you can assign an alias right there. Furthermore you're missing a `GROUP BY` if you want data for every track_id. So your query becomes this:

```
SELECT tdd.track_id, CONCAT(t.track_name, ' ',    t.track_description, ' ', t.keywords, ' ', tc.library_name, ' ', tc.label_name, ' ', tc.album_reference, ' ', 
GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)) AS track_data
FROM track_data AS tdd
JOIN tracks t 
ON tdd.track_id = t.track_id 
JOIN tracks_cache tc 
ON tc.track_id = t.track_id 
JOIN categories_to_track ct 
ON t.track_id = ct.track_id 
JOIN categories c 
ON c.category_id = ct.category_id
GROUP BY tdd.track_id
```

Note though, that this is not exactly right. The rule for using `GROUP BY` is, that every column you use in the `SELECT` clause should either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function should be applied on it. Reason is, that the rows for each group are kind of collapsed and when you don't apply an aggregate function, a random row for each group is displayed. MySQL allows this, but it's not really right. In your case you could apply the `MAX()` function on every column in your `CONCAT()` function.

Anyway, next problem will be, if you update the way you do it, you will get an error stating something like `you can't read and update from the same table at the same time`. You can prevent this by joining to your query instead of executing it in the `SET` section. This way MySQL produces a temporary table before actually updating.

```
UPDATE trackdata t 
JOIN (
    SELECT tdd.track_id, CONCAT(t.track_name, ' ',    t.track_description, ' ', t.keywords, ' ', tc.library_name, ' ', tc.label_name, ' ', tc.album_reference, ' ', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)) AS track_data
    FROM track_data AS tdd
    JOIN tracks t 
    ON tdd.track_id = t.track_id 
    JOIN tracks_cache tc 
    ON tc.track_id = t.track_id 
    JOIN categories_to_track ct 
    ON t.track_id = ct.track_id 
    JOIN categories c 
    ON c.category_id = ct.category_id
    GROUP BY tdd.track_id
) sq ON t.track_id = sq.track_id
SET t.track_data = sq.track_data;
```

Note though that I'm still too lazy to apply above mentioned aggregate functions on your columns :)

Comment: That is brilliant and has done just the job. Many thank fancyPants. Great work. It didn't update all my rows though which might be another issue and not down to the query. Thanks for your help.